# i need to pass a string of an output file to a variable so as i can use it globally all over my script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, perl, bash-scripting

> sample output

```
 RETENTION_INTERVAL
 ------------------
              10080
```

I need to pass the numeric value "10080" from the output file  to a variable .The condition should validate value and continue to next step,  if it returns an error it should terminate the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep`:

```
VARIABLE="$(grep -oE '[0-9]+' outputfile)"
```

- The `-o` flag of `grep` only prints the matched pattern.
- `-E` switches to extented regex.
- The regex means only match a digit that has 1 or more characters.
- That digit is saved into the variable.

Check it with:

```
$ echo $VARIABLE
10080
```